# Update list item by going Edit Properties-Dialog not closing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-form

In a SharePoint list, I tried to update items by going Edit Properties and make some changes and click save button. Dialog is not closing. And data is not saved.

Any reason for this?

Comment: Sounds like you may have a javascript error. Any custom branding or functionality added to this site?

Comment: Is it a custom list?

Comment: Yes. It is a custom list.